# How can I track a user's access to multiple pieces of content?

Tags: database, cookies

I am creating a site on which content will be stored for several different magazines.  Users will use a question and answer to gain access to the magazine.

Once they've been granted access, I would like them to continue to have access for a set period of time.

I'm thinking a database table could store cookie_id, issue_id and expiration. When a user accesses their first issue a cookie is stored on their computer containing a new, unique id. That unique ID, the issue id for the content they just accessed, and the expiration date get stored in the database.

If they access another issue, a new database entry is created but the cookie id is re-used.

When they return to the site the cookie is used to pull all related database entries and allow the user to re-visit any of those articles until they have expired.

Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with cookies is that they can be erased or corrupted (both unlikely but possible).

However, your solution is basically what I would do.

Here is what I would do...

when they login a cookie would be set with their userid (could be encrypted if desired). I wouldn't use any conglomeration of dates/times/random values because these values most likely be different each time the user returns.

On subsequent pages check to see if the **cookie** id is set (possibly save a database query - if you don't need to pull additional user info - and thus reduce load on the server).

I would use a database table and use their userid as the reference for further access to get previous issues read. If there are (or will be) a lot of users consider putting all info into one record in the database and inserting data in a specified format such as *issue1:date1, issue2:date2, etc*. this will only require 1 db query to update to add, update and/or delete entries.

However, for this I might seriously check into HTML5's local storage solutions - I haven't checked into using this yet or how well it is supported.

Comment: Thanks so much. Because access will be so short-lived (couple days at most, though the exact value hasn't been set) I will probably just run database cleanup of expired keys once a day to keep the database size reasonable. Thanks again for your help.